# Permutation multiplication of non-disjoint cycles in $S_4$

Tags: permutations

I am having an issue with calculating the product of permutation cycles for calculating commutators.

Consider $A_4$ and the commutator $[(123),(14)(23)]$

So we have $[(123),(14)(23)] = (132)(14)(23)(123)(14)(23)$

I think am calculating incorrectly after checking with an online permutation calculator. The result (using the online permutation calculator) I end up with is $[(123),(14)(23)] = (132)(14)(23)(123)(14)(23) = (12)(34)$

I am getting

$(132)\circ(14)(23)\circ (123)\circ (14)(23) = (13)(24)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. Why do you believe your result should be different?

Comment: okay that is a relief, I was using wolfram and another online permutation calculator to check and they both gave me $(12)(34)$

Comment: I think the calculator might be confusing the order of the composition, if you used something like this:
http://www.bananattack.com/permutations/

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I used.